Reading metes and bounds description
I have a property description and while researching how to read it I saw an article that mentioned they should be read backwards.
Quarter: NE S: 12 T: 17S R: 13W PT NWQNEQ PT SWQNEQ

I understand the first part is
Quarter: North East
Section: 12
Township 17 South
Range 13 West

I also found out that PT "probably" stands for points tangent, although I'm not 100% sure what that means. I also know that NWQNEQ stands for North West Quarter North East Quarter. I also understand that the NWQNEQ is a description of how to subdivide the section. This description comes off of a county assessor's website, I've been led to believe that those descriptions might be shorthand and contain ambiguity.
When quartering the section do I use SWQNEQ first or NWQNEQ first?

PT - Point of tangency. The point at which a curve ends and straight survey line begins.  https://www.directlinesoftware.com/survey.htm

It might help if you state your region; conventions differ geographically.

Which Principal Meridian?
